# drush up drupal fails on _drush_recursive_copy

Tags: drupal, drush

I am not able to upgrade to drupal 8.6.2 using drush 8.1.17. Unfortunately, drush does not provide the reason behind its failure. I have no clue of what do do next, and even how to debug it further. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

It follows an excerpt of the command `$ drush --debug up drupal`, you can find the (almost) complete log [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Qs6nVMmr) (I only removed the untar output to have a smaller file such that can be pasted on pastebin)

```
Calling chdir(/var/www/html) [94.7 sec, 14.02 MB]                                                                                                               [debug]
Calling is_readable(/tmp/drush_tmp_1539963315_5bc9f9b34e37c/drupal-8.6.2) [94.7 sec, 14.02 MB]                                                                  [debug]
Calling is_writable(/var/www/html) [94.7 sec, 14.02 MB]                                                                                                         [debug]
Calling rename(/tmp/drush_tmp_1539963315_5bc9f9b34e37c/drupal-8.6.2, /var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2) [94.7 sec, 14.02 MB]                                           [debug]
Calling _drush_recursive_copy(/tmp/drush_tmp_1539963315_5bc9f9b34e37c/drupal-8.6.2, /var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2) [94.7 sec, 14.02 MB]                            [debug]
Unable to copy /tmp/drush_tmp_1539963315_5bc9f9b34e37c/drupal-8.6.2 to /var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2. [116.8 sec, 14.02 MB]                                        [error]
Unable to move /tmp/drush_tmp_1539963315_5bc9f9b34e37c/drupal-8.6.2 to /var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2. [116.8 sec, 14.02 MB]                                        [error]
Updating project drupal failed. Attempting to roll back to previously installed version. [116.8 sec, 14.02 MB]                                                  [error]
Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode [116.8 sec, 13.92 MB]                                                                                                    [debug]
Rolling back update of Drupal core code ... [116.8 sec, 13.92 MB]                                                                                              [notice]
Verifying signature for svn version control engine. [116.8 sec, 13.92 MB]                                                                                       [debug]
Executing: svn info drupal-8.6.2
  sh: 1: svn: not found
Verifying signature for bzr version control engine. [117.1 sec, 10.88 MB]                                                                                       [debug]
Executing: bzr root drupal-8.6.2
  sh: 1: bzr: not found
Calling drush_delete_dir(/var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2, 1) [117.2 sec, 10.88 MB]                                                                                   [debug]
Calling is_readable(/var/www/drush-backups/the_site_com/20181019153440/drupal) [121.8 sec, 10.88 MB]                                                         [debug]
Calling is_writable(/var/www/html) [121.8 sec, 10.88 MB]                                                                                                        [debug]
Calling rename(/var/www/drush-backups/the_site_com/20181019153440/drupal, /var/www/html/drupal-8.6.2) [121.8 sec, 10.88 MB]                                  [debug]
Backups were restored successfully. [121.8 sec, 10.88 MB]                                                                                                          [ok]
```

A couple of info that might be useful:

```
root@host:/var/www/html# su www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'drush --version'
 Drush Version   :  8.1.17

root@host:/var/www/html# su www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'drush core-status'
 Drupal version                  :  8.5.3
 Site URI                        :  http://default
 Database driver                 :  mysql
 Database hostname               :  the-database-hostname
 Database port                   :
 Database username               :  the-database-username
 Database name                   :  the-database-name
 Database                        :  Connected
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
 Drupal user                     :
 Default theme                   :  mytheme
 Administration theme            :  seven
 PHP configuration               :  /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
 PHP OS                          :  Linux
 Drush script                    :  /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version                   :  8.1.17
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp
 Drush configuration             :
 Drush alias files               :
 Install profile                 :  standard
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/html
 Drupal Settings File            :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path                       :  sites/default
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
 Sync config path                :  sites/default/files/config_xeVhGsWgDSMcUJNlA97zQiNNekC93e2MhX5aEtO5UcOtKQnwq7fjEB9K6Bk15kj53APj6h8Ibg/sync
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably very easy to explain.

Drupal 8 now requires Drush 9.

See the chart on http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install. `D8.3-` means with Drush 8 your Drupal can not be greater than or equal to `8.3`.

[image]

I don't know how far you already got with your project. But you may consider to restart with [`drupal-composer/drupal-project`](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) which already always will have the right Drush version as local dependency on board. And it will also tell you to **not update Drupal with Drush anymore**. Do that with Composer instead.